# Get values before first space in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I am using SQL SERVER 2016.

The column named as Fullname has value like.

```
Raj A Malhotra
Kartik   Naidu
Stephen Jose  Mick
Tom    Alter
```

The Space is not same after Raj,Kartik,Stephen and Tom.

I am trying to get values before first space.

Output

```
Raj
Kartik
Stephen
Tom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use string functions:

```
select t.*, left(fullname, charindex(' ', fullname) - 1) as firstname
from mytable t
```